# please help me: conatct form for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a problem with wordpress when I use any conatct form it shows me that the email has been sent but in reality the email is not received by the recipient. Can somebody help me please

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking if your emails actually have a chance of reaching anyone https://www.mail-tester.com/

Comment: Apparently the emails are not received because the test performed does not show me a score

Comment: That means your server doesn't send them at all. Try reaching out support, see what they say

Comment: hello, I will come back to you to answer you, I have carried out some tests and it turns out that the server is sending emails and the problem is not there. do you have any other suggestions?